# Dependant source in RLC series circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

I want to create a differential equation in the circuit below in terms if current but that dependent source is confusing me

[image: circuit]

(From the OP's comments)

I am considering current $i$ in the loop so my equation becomes

$$4i - v_C + L \frac{di}{dt} + \mathrm{voltage\, across\, dependent\, source} = 0$$

What will be the voltage across the dependent source in this condition?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Please provide more explanation about the reason for your confusion, and show your attempt to create the differential equation.

Comment: I am considering current "i" in the loop so my equation becomes

Comment: 4i - Vc + Ldi/dt + "voltage across dependent source" = 0

Comment: What will be the voltage across dependent source in this condition

Comment: The voltage across the dependent source is always $3v_C$. The question is, how does $v_C$ depend on $i$?

Comment: how can you say that voltage across dependent current source is 3Vc. 
Question is to develop a differential equation for the circuit in variable "i" and time "t"

Comment: @sammygerbil, that's a [voltage controlled current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_source) (VCCS) in the diagram and so the voltage across is independent of the current through.  The coefficient multiplying $v_C$ is not dimensionless; it has units of conductance, i.e., the VCCS in the diagram has a *transconductance of* 3 mhos.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a series circuit, the clockwise current $i$ is determined by the voltage controlled current source (VCCS) and is thus given by

$$i = -3\mho \cdot v_C$$

But, by the capacitor equation, it is also the case that

$$i = C\frac{dv_C}{dt}$$

Can you take it from here?